# Force rules for build and deployment

Tags: deployment, msbuild, build, cruisecontrol.net, rules

Our web project is source-controlled with SVN. It contains MSBuild file to build local, test and production builds. We also use CruiseControl.NET to deploy production and test versions to servers manually (not after every commit).

The question is how to check that if production deployment is being done using CC.NET web project is built using production build (not test or other)? How to force specific steps to be executed when building and deploying to production (like compress JS and CSS, compile with debug="false", etc...)? Now it is possible for every developer make changes in MSBuild file (so he/she can forget to compress JS on production build, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I used CruiseControl with NAnt extensively, but not MSBuild.  Do you have different MSBuild files for each build type (i.e. local/test/prod)?  Could you have a single one that can be parameterized such that your CCNet integrators can explicitly call the appropriate options for the target environment?  That's how I have my continuous integration versus release candidate builds configured in CCNet. A single master NAnt build script and a different CC integrator for each target env with the necessary build parameters (be them targets or property values).  I imagine you could do something quite similar with MSBuild vars/targets.

Comment: Yes, we use single build file and pass parameters to it. However, that build file can be modified by any developer and if for example we add new feature to our deployment script and developer forgets to add it to deployment script, that causes problems. How to check that build file included new deployment "feature"?